# Openlaszlo migration issues

Tags: openlaszlo

When i am trying to migrate the code from OL 3.3 to 4.9 i am getting this error. I have followed the steps mentioned here.
http://wiki.openlaszlo.org/Runtime_Differences
But still i am getting this error.

```
 [exec] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
     [exec]     at org.openlaszlo.compiler.ClassModel.sortKey(ClassModel.java:235)
     [exec]     at org.openlaszlo.compiler.ClassModel.compareTo(ClassModel.java:244)
     [exec]     at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:560)
     [exec]     at java.util.TreeSet.add(TreeSet.java:255)
     [exec]     at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:334)
     [exec]     at java.util.TreeSet.addAll(TreeSet.java:312)
     [exec]     at java.util.TreeSet.<init>(TreeSet.java:160)
     [exec]     at org.openlaszlo.compiler.ViewSchema.resolveClassModels(ViewSchema.java:362)
     [exec]     at org.openlaszlo.compiler.Compiler.updateRootSchema(Compiler.java:809)
     [exec]     at org.openlaszlo.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:452)
     [exec]     at org.openlaszlo.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:199)
     [exec]     at org.openlaszlo.compiler.Main.compile(Main.java:463)
     [exec]     at org.openlaszlo.compiler.Main.lzc(Main.java:402)
     [exec]     at org.openlaszlo.compiler.Main.main(Main.java:105)
```

Has anyone come across the same type. Please let me know what is the solution.

Comment: That looks like an error message which has been reported in the past [link](http://forum.openlaszlo.org/showthread.php?p=48130), when the compiler had problems finding a class which is used implicitly used within your code. Could you please with with 5.0 (trunk) if the problem still persists?

Comment: @raju: Ok.. I'll try that and see

Comment: If you are migrating your code, I'd recommend that you migrate to 5.0 directly. 4.9 has been released a long time ago (Oct 2010), and a log of bugs got fixed and features got added in 5.0.

Comment: @r.bitter: Thank you..I have started migrating it to 5.0..

Comment: Would be good if you provide the answer to your own question, just saying that you upgraded to OpenLaszlo 5.0 - and the problem went away. By doing that we'd have an accepted answer, and others could follow your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem existed even in the 5.0 version but later by removing the dependencies one by one, i found that one of the class's default placement value is a constraint when i remove the constraint and give the proper name. The error was resolved.